# Can the verb "underline" be used to emphasise a word?

Tags: meaning

Example:

> You will never do that again and I underline never!

Probably "and I mean it" is used this way.

Answer (score 1):

As you surmise, the usage is metaphorical, suggesting that if it were written, it would be emphasized with an underline. Verbalizing punctuation or other mechanics is not uncommon in informal speech.

> You will never do that again, period [full stop]!
>
> You will capital-N never do that again!
>
> You will never do that again, dot dot dot, never!

Answer (score 0):

You are brilliant. Absolutely brilliant idiomatic usage of language. However, when writing it I would write it either as

> You will never do that again and I underline *never*!

Or,

> You will never do that again and I underline "never"!

When spoken, it would reinforce comprehension to do a brief Harlem shake when enunciating the word "never".

Or, provide a more executive feel, by doing the traditional quotation marks finger gestures for the word "never".

Or, say the sentence in a more stuffy way

> You will never do that again and I underline quote-unquote never!